# Determine if PDF searchable

Tags: c#, pdf, ocr, ghostscript

how to Determine/validate programmatically if the PDF is searchable or not, scanned pdf or not. I know some questions are the same but some not answered properly

```
  if (openPdfFileDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string strfilename = openPdfFileDialog.FileName;
            pdfImageBox.Enabled = true;
            btnSave.Enabled = true;
            txt_Save.Enabled = true;
            btnAdd.Enabled = true;
            txtOcr1.Enabled = true;
            this.OpenPDF(openPdfFileDialog.FileName);
            ext.Text = strfilename;
            txt_Save.Text = ext.Text;

        }
```

Comment: Didn't you ask this a few hours ago?

Comment: What do you mean by searchable.

Comment: I think that's, my classmate, haha.

Comment: if the pdf is searchable the text can highlight, if its no the pdf is just like an image. , now the problem is how can we validate if the pdf is searchable or not

Comment: I would interpret 'searchable' to mean 'succesfully searchable' which requires rather mote than the presence of some text. The only guaranteed way to search a PDF file is if the file has ToUnicode CMaps for each font in the PDF file. So, IMO the best way to check whether a PDF file is searchable is to check for the presence of fonts (no fonts = not searchable at all). If fonts are present, do all the fonts have ToUnicode CMaps. If so, its searchable. If not, then it **might** be searchable, depending on the Encoding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the PDF document contains only scanned images, then it won’t have any text in it. We can extract the text from the PDF document and check if it returns empty string then we can conclude that it is a scanned PDF.
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-text-extraction

Assuming if your searchable PDF do not have images in it, than you can do image extraction. If images are present then the PDF document have scanned images.
https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-image-extraction

Note: I work for Syncfusion.